# Glyphicon inside button not visible

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I would like to put glyphicon inside button. I don't know why it's not visible. The only thing that is visible is text, but not glyphicon.

[Here](http://codepen.io/FrenkyB/pen/mWGYJb?editors=1100) is example. Problem is with this button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span>3</button>
```

Comment: Your code works fine on my website. Make sure you have include correct bootstrap css files.

Comment: From codepen example you are able to see glyphicon?

Comment: I think you didn't import your bootstrap library.

Comment: You forgot to add bootstrap css  https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css

Comment: I've added bootstrap, but version 4.0 alpha. When I've changed this to 3.3.7, all was good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span> 3 </button>
```

Comment: I guess the problem was with codepen link. It points to bootstrap 4.0 alpha. When I've changed link to version 3.3.7, everything started working normally.

Comment: may be bt you should include bootstrap cdn or download it

Answer (score 1):

Working example using [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_glyphs&stacked=h)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Glyphicon Examples</h2>
 
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span> 3
    </button>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```